# Modification of specific sections of bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

How do I modify specific sections of bytecode to add things in?

What I mean by this is that I know what class, and what method (or field), and what line number I want to modify, but I want to know how I would actually go about modifying the bytecode at a specific line / field of a class.

Say I have a class, *GammaController*

```
public class GammaController {
    private int gamma = 60;

    public int getScreenGamma() {
        return gamma;
    }

    public void setScreenGamma(int gamma) {
        this.gamma = gamma;
    }
}
```

But I want to change GammaController.setScreenGamma() to not allow values above 100, without editing the file. I know that the method is at line 8 (we'll ignore packages for now), and a check for above 100 would have to go at line 9, moving the part of the method doing the setting down 1 line.

Let's say I also know the bytecode that will do the check. What I want to do is run an application targeting a jar containing GammaController.class, and have the application modify the class with the bytecode that checks the value to make sure it isn't over 100. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Honestly, it might be easier to just replace `GammaController.class` wholesale with a custom-compiled version, instead of mucking with bytecode.

Comment: It would be better to create a wrapper class for the `GammaController` and set the new business logic inside or even extend the `GammaController` class. A good design solution is 9001 times better than hacking third party libraries.

Comment: I should probably have said this in the question, but GammaController is purely an example. The actual case is modifying something without having to update about 70+ hooks in that things code every time it updates.

Comment: The biggest obstacle of course is that you have to learn bytecode first. You normally can't just plug in extra code an expect it to work, especially with the new StackMap tables. You need to read the JVM specification first. Also, it depends on how you want to modify the class. If you're modifying them at runtime or programatically, ASM is probably the best bet. If you want to do it manually, I'd recommend using a human friendly, offline tool like the disassembler/assembler I wrote.

Comment: Automatically is the plan. I know my way around reading bytecode in small sections, and for the simple things I plan on doing I am fine with what I know. But using ASM will not require much of that knowledge from what I can see.

Comment: @DziNeIT Well to take your example, the code you want to add contains a conditional, so you'll need to update the StackMapTable as well, and that gets complicated. You'll also have to update the offsets of all the jumps and exception handlers in the function. And in rare cases, you'll have to make them wide to hold the new offset. Assuming the original had debugging information that you want to preserve, like LineNumberTable and so on, you'll have to update those too. And you need to update the code and attribute lengths, though ASM may do this for you.

Comment: Does ASM not handle the StackMapTable for me? I was under the impression it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ASM 2.0](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) or 3.0/[4.0](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) (depending on your Java version). To do what I think you want to do, you'll need to use a `ClassVisitor` and modify some values (via `VisitField` etc.). You will then need to reload the class.

This is nontrivial, but the ASM people provide some very verbose documentation. Happy hacking.

Comment: Thanks for the information and pointing me towards ASM. I presume ASM 4 is for Java 7, so I'll be using that one I think.

Answer (score 2):

[AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) (or any AOP library) could be of some use here. It allows you to define *pointcuts*, such as when a particular method is called (or when a field is defined among other things). You can then apply *advice*, which is something you do before/after the *join point* (the join point is where the pointcut was applied).

For example,

Apply advice that validates that the gamma value is < 100 whenever that method is called. If the value is invalid, throw an exception. If it is valid, continue as normal.

If you really want to modify individual lines of code that don't fall into the categories of what pointcuts can handle, you can use the ASM libraries as suggested by @DavidTitarenco

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think ASM is what I'll go with, at least for now.